# Javascript/ Arrays/ Delete an object/ Add an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I need to do some tasks to get an internship as a front-end dev. The tasks are:

Create a dashboard where i can see employees and customers. See attached file.

Requests:

1. Dinamically display the list of employees and customers from two
   arrays.
2. All Employees can be deleted except the last.
3. New Customers can be added.

I have done all these tasks, but i have a problem on 3'rd task. I have found the index of "employees"array's object that should be deleted, the function deletes the chosen object from array, but how to display this change in the input field (to delete the chosen object from the displayed list of employees)? Please help me !!!

```js
var employees = [
  {
    firstname: "Dorin",
    lastname: "Petrescu"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Sergiu",
    lastname: "Galescu"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Vasile",
    lastname: "Marcu"
  },
];


var customers = [
  {
    firstname: "Valentin",
    lastname: "Condratiuc"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Petru",
    lastname: "Lesco"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Oleg",
    lastname: "Tataru"
  },
];


//1) Display the list of customers and employees
function init(){
  // document.getElementById("names").value = "";
    document.getElementById("names").value = localStorage.getItem("user");
    for ( i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
      var needed_area = document.getElementById("names");
      needed_area.value +="\n"+ customers[i].firstname +" " + customers[i].lastname;
}
}

function init2(){
  for ( i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    var selected_area = document.getElementById("names2");
    selected_area.value +="\n"+employees[i].firstname +" " + employees[i].lastname;
  }
}




//2) Delete a Specific Employee

function delete_employee() {
  var delete_item = prompt ("The name of employee you want to delete");
  index = employees.findIndex(x => x.firstname==delete_item);
  console.log(index);
  employees.splice(index, 1);
  var selected_area = document.getElementById("names2");

}




//3) New Customers can be added :
function push_new_customer() {
  var selected_name = prompt("The name of the new customer!");
  var selected_surname = prompt("The surname of the new customer!");
  customers.push({ firstname: selected_name, lastname: selected_surname });
  var needed_area = document.getElementById("names");
  needed_area.value+="\n" +selected_name+ " " +selected_surname;
  // localStorage.setItem("user", needed_area.value);

}
```

```css
textarea {
      height: 200px;
      width: 250px;
    }
```

```html
<body onload="init(); init2();">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h2>New Customer</h2>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2>Registered Customers</h2>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2>Delete an employee</h2>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h2>Current Employees</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="your name" id="add" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)"> -->
        <button onclick="push_new_customer();" type="button" name="button">Add a new customer!</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea id="names">
        </textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="your name" id="add" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)"> -->
        <button onclick="delete_employee();" type="button" name="button">Delete an employee</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea id="names2">

        </textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </table>

</body>
```

I have attached some images to explain my question.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c52m.png)

Comment: Call init() ? And clear the content before doing so

Answer (score 0):

Considering your code structure, and the fact you are using a textarea, you can clear the select and call the `init2` function you created:

```
function delete_employee() {
  var delete_item = prompt ("The name of employee you want to delete");
  index = employees.findIndex(x => x.firstname==delete_item);
  console.log(index);
  employees.splice(index, 1);
  var selected_area = document.getElementById("names2");
  selected_area.value = "";
  init2();
}
```

But it would be nicer if you used some library/framework to bind view and model.